# For a measure $\mu $ *does it exists* a sequence $\{E _n \} $ of sets such that $\mu(E _n)<1/2^n $ for every $n $?

Tags: measure-theory

If $\mu $ is a measure defined on a measure space $(X, M, \mu ) $, can I claim that there exists a sequence $\{E _n \} $ of set in $M $ such that for every $n $, $\mu ( E _n) <1/2^n $?

If so, what does this follow from?

(I don't want the trivial case where $E _n =\emptyset $ for every $n $.) (Also, this is for a proof that if $ \nu $ is finite and absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu $ then for every $E \in M $, if  $\epsilon >0 $ then there exists a $ \delta >0$: if $\mu (E)< \delta $, then $\nu(E)<\epsilon$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not necessarily, take the counting measure for example (if you don't want $E_n = \emptyset$).

Comment: Regarding the final comment in the question, I think the final $\delta$ should have been $\epsilon$. And do note that if there is no $E$ with $\mu(E)<\delta$, the implication is trivially satisfied.